# Can the strong reference returned from WeakReference's get method cause a memory leak in AsyncTask onProgressUpdate?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, weak-references

I want to use `WeakReference` to avoid a memory leak in `AsyncTask`. The examples I find online only use the `get()` method in `onPostExecute`, but I also want to use it to update the progress. Now I wonder if that very frequent call of the `get` method can in itself cause a memory leak?

```
private static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    ExampleAsyncTask(MainActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activityReference.get() == null) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground started");
        for (int i = 1; i < integers[0]; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);
        }

        return "Finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost has no strong reference as far as the `get` and `onProgressUpdate` are concerned because you are using local variable which will go out of scope, the moment `onProgressUpdate` is finished.

So basically everytime your code is accessing the reference, retrieved from `get()` method so it is safe. Although it would have been an issue, if you would have kept a reference, declared outside `onProgressUpdate` method

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted to know :)

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Comment: Unfortunatly somehow `get` in the scope of the method still returns the MainActivity after leaving over the back button. I checked it in logcat.

Comment: try applying null check `activityReference.get() == null`  or `activity == null` in logcat, because type will not change, only null reference is the concerned

Comment: It still keeps returning the activity. I don't understand this

Comment: @FlorianWalther could you check that whether this returned value is null or not, and is there any crash?

Comment: I added the null check but it still returns the activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166618/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-florian-walther).

Comment: `It still keeps returning the activity. I don't understand this ` - because it hasn't been garbage collected yet. An activities onDestroy callback method doesn't mean it is being removed from memory. The reference is still valid until it is garbage collected (unless it gets leaked by some other erroneous strong reference), but importantly not held onto by your weakreference.